# Restarting methods in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, methods, return

I am making a battleships game in Javascript. At the moment, I am working on placing the boats, and making sure that the boats aren't placed on top of each other.

To do this, I am using three methods, one that chooses a position for the boat, one that builds the boat and makes a boundary around it, and a third that executes these two methods. When the second method makes a boundary around the boat, it does so by setting a property `boatHere` to `1`, and then in the third function, it checks to see whether the first function has chosen a position that already has the property `boatHere = 1`. I want to check whether there is a boat there already, and restart the third function in order to place a boat elsewhere. Here is the code:

```
    placeBoat : function() { //chooses position, checks to see if eligible and builds boat
        for (boatNum = 1; boatNum < 4; boatNum++) {
            this.selectPos();
            if (document.getElementById(boatPos).boatHere == 1) {
                return;
            }
            else {
                this.buildBoat();               
            }
        }   
    }, 

    selectPos : function() { //chooses position 
            xPos = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8);
            yPos = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1);
            boatPos = "cell_" + xPos + "_" + yPos;
    },

    buildBoat : function() { //builds boat 3 tiles long and boundary 7 tiles long
        for (boatLen = 1; boatLen < 4; boatLen++) {
            xPos = xPos + 1;
            boatPos = "cell_" + xPos + "_" + yPos;
            document.getElementById(boatPos).hasBoat = 1;
            document.getElementById(boatPos).style.backgroundColor = "brown";
            console.log("placed one tile");
        }
        xPos = xPos - 6;
        for (boatBox = 1; boatBox < 8; boatBox++) {
            xPos++;
            boatPos = "cell_" + xPos + "_" + yPos;
            document.getElementById(boatPos).boatHere = 1;
            document.getElementById(boatPos).innerHTML = "  X";//visual reminder of where boundary is
        }
```

Comment: beware, undeclared global variables everywere!!

Answer (score 2):

You could use a separate `placeSingleBoat()` function to place a boat that returns if it was successful or not. The `placeBoat()` function can then call `placeSingleBoat()` as often as necessary until it was successful:

```
placeSingleBoat: function(boatNum) {  //chooses position, checks to see if eligible and builds boat
    this.selectPos();
    if (document.getElementById(boatPos).boatHere == 1) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        this.buildBoat();               
    }
    return true;       
},

placeBoat : function() {
    for (boatNum = 1; boatNum < 4; boatNum++) {
        var placed = false;
        while (!placed) {
            placed = this.placeSingleBoat(boatNum);
        }
    }
},
```

Comment: You can remove the `else {` `}` part. The `while` loop can be reduced to `while (!this.placeSingleBoat(boatNum)) {}`.

Comment: if there are less than 3 spots available. Your while loop will never stop.

Comment: @AwakeningByte: How would placing 4 ships ever work if there are only 3 spots available?

Comment: It won't. Could cause bugs when this code is consumed without taking care of this problem .

Answer (score -1):

From your description it looks like you want this:

```
    for (boatNum = 1; boatNum < 4; boatNum++) {
        do {
            this.selectPos();
        } while (document.getElementById(boatPos).boatHere == 1);
        this.buildBoat();               
    }
```

I.e. keep selecting a new position until you find one that isn't occupied already, then build a boat there.

Comment: i was trying to say, if there are less than 3 spots available. Your while loop will be infinity.

Comment: @AwakeningByte That's true, but that can be ruled out statically by the calling code (by making sure the board always has enough tiles for all boats).